# Cannot get project to compile using Fragment, Ad Services and Picasso

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I had to run a disk check on my machine, after running this and launching Android Studio it could not find an SDK so I installed one with the wizard.

After this my code is not compiling it was all working fine before:

[image]

I have these set in my build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.3'
```

I have tried to Ivalidate Cache and restart but doesn't compile.

Comment: Have you also included support v4 library ?
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'

Comment: Just included it but it doesn't even give me an option to resync :(

Comment: well that's strange, there might be some problem with your gradle. the screenshot you attached clearly says the problem lies with not including support v4 lib.

Comment: no there was no problem before and the image is just an example, picasso and ad isn't compiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this by going to File > Settings > Plugins > Unchecking Firebase Services and re-checking Android Support.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close Android Studio and Go to your sdk location
2. Find a folder called "build-tools". Delete that folder. For a safe side, keep a backup before deleting.
3. Reopen Android Studio and build. This worked for me !!